# ColdFusion place holders for conditional logic

Tags: templates, coldfusion

I'm wondering whether anyone can refer me to a library of code that would assist in allowing users to modify conditional logic within their templates instead of seeing ColdFusion code.

An example would be if a page contained a table of data, we would like to allow users to be able to edit the template of the page with special commands they can insert. So for the table of data normally we might write:

```
<cfoutput>
<table>
   <cfloop query="myContent">
      <tr><td>#mycontent.cell1#</td>
          <td>#mycontent.cell2#</td>
          <td>#mycontent.cell3#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```

I've seen on some website CMS's that users can edit their templates with specific placeholders like:

```
%output%
<table>
 %query="myContent"%
    <tr><td>[mycontent.cell1]</td>
        <td>[mycontent.cell2]</td>
        <td>[mycontent.cell3]</td>
    </tr>
    %/query%
</table>
%output%
```

I figure it most likely wouldn't look like this, but I'm hoping that someone has created some sort of open source parser that allows for the users to modify templates without writing CF code. Alternately, if there is some kind of library on another platform that does something like this which I can look into to see if I can replicate it for ColdFusion.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Mustache.cfc](https://github.com/rip747/Mustache.cfc) which is an implementation of the [Mustache templating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_%28template_system%29) in CFML.